# SaveAs FileFormat:=xlExcel5 saving only 16K of 23K rows in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that splits a large file (900k rows) by cost center. The macro finds the beginning row and ending row of each cost center. It then copies the cost center data to a new workbook and saves it. Finally the macro moves to the new cost center and repeats until it has gone through the large file.

This month, a particular cost center has 23k rows. The "new" file only has 16k rows. I stepped through the code and it is copying the entire data set (23k rows) and pasting it in the "new" workbook.

The next line of code is:

```
Workbooks(MyTemplate).SaveAs Filename:=SaveName, FileFormat:=xlExcel5, Password:=MyPass(Y), ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

When the macro is finished, I open this particular cost center and there are only 16k rows.

Why is this happening and where are the missing 7k rows?

Comment: If I recall, Excel version 5 is limited to 16,384 rows.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/366468/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-rows-in-a-microsoft-excel-xls-or-xlsx ... time to join the modern era!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're issue is within your SaveAs statement:

```
Workbooks(MyTemplate).SaveAs Filename:=SaveName, FileFormat:=xlExcel5, Password:=MyPass(Y), ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

Specifically: `FileFormat:=xlExcel5`

This is saving the file in the very old Excel 5 (1994) format. At that time, Excel sheets were limited to 16,384 rows.

So while you're able to copy your 23,000 rows, when it comes to saving the file Excel is only saving the first 16,384 in case it ever gets loaded by Excel v5. More rows would cause a crash.

If you insist on keeping the XLS format and not the later XLSX, you might want to change your code to:

```
Workbooks(MyTemplate).SaveAs Filename:=SaveName, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:=MyPass(Y), ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

This will keep the file as XLS format, but in the later version 8 format which supports up to 65,536 rows.

If you want to move into the 21st century, use `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` - but you'll need to tweak the filename suffix to **XLSX** of course. This would support 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I did more research, after posting this question, on Excel file formats.  I ended up changing  the format to xlExcel8 and found that solved the issue.

This is an old macro and I assumed this has happened before but no one ever bothered to notify us.  I took the quick fix because the user was trying to meet a deadline and split all of the files.  I will definitely change the file suffix to XLSX and update the code again to get current.  Thank you for the advice and all of the information provided.  Both my user and I appreciate your help.....